# What's the difference between these two nservicebus statements

Tags: async-await, nservicebus

In one documentation they say IHandleMessages handler hast to be written this way (signature is automatically generated when I choose to "Implement interface" option in Visual Studio):

```
public class PlaceOrderHandler : IHandleMessages<PlaceOrder>
{
    public Task Handle(PlaceOrder message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        var orderPlaced = new OrderPlaced { OrderId = message.OrderId };

        return context.Publish(orderPlaced);
    }
}
```

While another documentation says it has to be written this way:

```
public class PlaceOrderHandler : IHandleMessages<PlaceOrder>
{
    public async Task Handle(PlaceOrder message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        var orderPlaced = new OrderPlaced { OrderId = message.OrderId };

        await context.Publish<OrderPlaced>(e => { e.OrderId = message.OrderId; });

    }
}
```

I wonder what is the difference between these two statements, can someone explain in simple language?

Which option is the right one?

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct options. The difference between the two is how a **single** asynchronous operation is handles in the `Handle` method.

In the first case, a `Task` is returned as-is. In the second case, publishing is awaited within the `Handle` method. The difference? In the first case no async state machine is created by the compiler as the task of publishing returned back. In the second scenario, a state machine is created.

Which option is the right one to use? They are both correct options. If a method is called frequently and you care for the unnecessary allocations not to take place, returnng a single task without awaiting is more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand. What is state machine? In first case the return type is Task, so I have to use a return statement. In the second case - exactly the same, return type is Task, why doesnt the compiler force me to use return statement? I cannot comprehend this logic. AS far as I understand async-await mean nothing they are just markers, if the method has a return type, it must have return statement, isnt it right?

Comment: "If a method is called frequently and you care for the unnecessary allocations not to take place, returning a single task without awaiting is more efficient." - I dont know how frequently it will be called and what means "frequently"? 2 times a minute, 500 times a minute? Do I care for the unnecessary allocations? I dont even understand what that means? Do I care? How many allocations are we talking about, what kind of allocations? How do I even know about them? Where do I see them?

Comment: You can go with `async Task` and `await` for 100% of your code. `Task` with `return` is an optimization. This is not unique to NServiceBus, but the way asynchronious code works. If you want to dig into that, you'll find out that each time you're using the `await` keyward, an asynchronous state machine is generated behind the scenes by the C# compiler. Again, details that if you don't care for, you can skip and live in peace by using `async Task / await` all of the time.

Comment: What if I have multiples calls to publish within a handler which may or may not all be invoked, depending on control flow?  Should I await them all, or does it matter if they are unawaited?  is context.Publish(foo) OK, or do I always need to use await context.Publish(foo)?

Comment: If you have more than one publish, always await.